# Retrieving the last inserted rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table which contains GUID and Name columns and I need to retrieve the last inserted rows so I can load it into table2.

But how would I find out the latest data in Table1. I seem to be lost at this I have read similar posts posing the same question but the answers don't seem to work for my situation.

I am using SQL Server 2008 and I upload my data using SSIS

Comment: do you store posttime in the table?

Comment: Note, SCOPE_IDENTITY() and @@IDENTITY will not work for a table with GUID primary key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 - One way to do this is with triggers.  Check out my blog entry that shows how to copy data from one table to another on a insert.

Triggers to replicate data = http://craftydba.com/?p=1995

However, like most things in life, there is **overhead** with triggers.  If you are bulk loading a ton of data via SSIS, this can add up.

2 - Another way to do this is to add a modify date to your first table and modify your SSIS package.

```
ALTER TABLE [MyTable1] 
ADD [ModifyDate] [datetime] NULL DEFAULT GETDATE();
```

Next, change your SSIS package.  In the control flow, add an execute SQL task.  Insert data from [MyTable1] to [MyTable2] using TSQL.

```
INSERT INTO [MyTable2] 
SELECT * FROM [MyTable1] 
WHERE [ModifyDate] >= 'Start Date/Time Of Package';
```

Execute SQL Task  =
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141003.aspx

This will be quicker than a data flow or execute OLEDB command since you are working with the data on the server.

Comment: I like really like your idea. I didnt mention Table2 is a linked server table would your menthod be ideal in a linked server?

Comment: Use option 2 if table 2 is a linked server.  I never tried triggers with a linked table target, sounds slow and a-lot of overhead.